# Unique Sets Permutations R

Tags: r, set, unique, permutation

Is there a way to generate all the unique sets of the following permutations, where I am able to change N and R easily.

```
library(gtools)
x <- c("A","B","C","D")
x <- permutations(n=4,r=2,v=x)
x
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "D" 
[4,] "B"  "A" 
[5,] "B"  "C" 
[6,] "B"  "D" 
[7,] "C"  "A" 
[8,] "C"  "B" 
[9,] "C"  "D" 
[10,] "D"  "A" 
[11,] "D"  "B" 
[12,] "D"  "C"
```

For example sets 1 and 4 are not unique, AB and BA contain the same characters.

The following list is unique, and this is what I want.

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,] "A"  "B" 
[2,] "A"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "D" 
[4,] "B"  "C"
[5,] "B"  "D"
[6,] "C"  "D"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conbn` would give you what you need:

```
 #combn gives you the combinations, t is only used to transpose the matrix
 t(combn(x, 2))
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,] "A"  "B" 
#[2,] "A"  "C" 
#[3,] "A"  "D" 
#[4,] "B"  "C" 
#[5,] "B"  "D" 
#[6,] "C"  "D"
```